# Why does RAM access any memory address in O(1) time?

Tags: ram

When we work with arrays, for example, assign a[10000] = 3, what it does is it first add 10000 * sizeof(int) to memory address of a, and then access that memory address. The question is, why does accessing such memory address takes only O(1) time? Basically, what's the magic behind random access memory such that it takes the same time accessing address #1 vs. address #1,000,000?

Comment: I think it has something to do with RAM being just a bunch of transistors/capacitors and not a tape. Electric signals travel really really fast.

Comment: It simply takes the same time to access (to address) any arbitrary memory cell. This is due to the technical design and differs for different storage media as disks, magnetic hard drives, etc

Comment: That's more or less true for (SRAM-based) caches because of the hardware implementation but not for modern (D)RAM, which is slow and therefore heavily cached. Memory accesses then depend on what's currently in cache and what isn't as well as on your memory access patterns (<= if the hardware prefetcher is of any help or not).

Answer (score 1):

Random access memory is by definition memory that can provide the contents at any address in a constant amount of time. That's the 'random access' bit, and what distinguishes it from other types of memory.

There's no magic involved; there are just n locations, and whomever is accessing memory provides the details to select one of them.

In most implementations every word of memory is an identical piece of electronics. You're just selecting which is connected to the bus.

Answer (score 0):

> for example, assign `a[10000] = 3`, what it does is it first add `10000 * sizeof(int)` to memory address of `a`, and then access that memory address.

That's exactly right. Many CPUs have a single addressing mode to access data at an offset from the base, where the base is a fixed number and the offset is in a register, or vice versa.

> what's the magic behind random access memory such that it takes the same time accessing address #1 vs. address #1,000,000?

The same "magic" that lets you add two numbers in a fixed amount of time, regardless of the values of the numbers being added. In other words, it does not matter if you add `1` or `1000000` to the base of, say, `2000000000`: it takes the same number of cycles.